# ClosedXML writing to all sheets in Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, closedxml

I've been working with ClosedXML for the past 24 hours, I feel as if I've gotten everything out of it I need except for one bug. I have an existing workbook that has 3 sheets in it currently. Similar data will be on each sheet but it will be different values. I've attached my pseudo code below (Specific variable names have been changed to protect the innocent).

The code below is inside a foreach loop as I'm looping thru a large set of SQL tables. The problem is, ClosedXML or something I have done is writing the same data to all sheets and overwriting the sheets in front and behind it. I feel perhaps I've done something obvious but I've been staring at the same code for awhile and can no longer see the glaring error. Any help would be appreciated!

```
  //Workbook = new workbook and filepath are initialized outside of the loop
                    var worksheet = workbook.Worksheet(1);

                //This is used to help me identify what column it is in, it references an array of alphabet characters later
                int column = 0;

                if(loopCt <= 2)
                {
                    worksheet.Cell("A1").Value = "Identifier";
                    worksheet.Cell("B1").Value = "XYZ Day 1";
                    worksheet.Cell("C1").Value = "XYZ Day 2";
                    worksheet.Cell("D1").Value = "XYZ Day 3";
                    worksheet.Cell("E1").Value = "XYZ Day 4";
                    worksheet.Cell("F1").Value = "XYZ Day 5";
                    worksheet.Cell("G1").Value = "XYZ Day 6";
                    worksheet.Cell("H1").Value = "XYZ Day 7";
                    worksheet.Cell("I1").Value = "XYZ Day 8";
                    worksheet.Cell("J1").Value = "XYZ Day 9";
                    worksheet.Cell("K1").Value = "XYZ Day 10";
                    worksheet.Cell("L1").Value = "XYZ Weekly Total";
                }

                worksheet.Cell($"A{loopCt}").Value = item.identifier;

                for (int i = 0; i < XYZDaily.Count(); i++)
                {
                    column += 1;
                    worksheet.Cell($"{alphabet[column]}{loopCt}").Value = XYZDaily[i];

                }

                worksheet.Cell($"L{loopCt}").Value = XYZWeek;

                workbook.Save();

                //QRS Export

                var worksheetQRS = workbook.Worksheet(2);
                int columnQRS = 0;

                if (QRSCt <= 2)
                {
                    worksheetQRS.Cell("A1").Value = "Identifier";
                    worksheetQRS.Cell("B1").Value = "QRS Day 1";
                    worksheetQRS.Cell("C1").Value = "QRS Day 2";
                    worksheetQRS.Cell("D1").Value = "QRS Day 3";
                    worksheetQRS.Cell("E1").Value = "QRS Day 4";
                    worksheetQRS.Cell("F1").Value = "QRS Day 5";
                    worksheetQRS.Cell("G1").Value = "QRS Day 6";
                    worksheetQRS.Cell("H1").Value = "QRS Day 7";
                    worksheetQRS.Cell("I1").Value = "QRS Day 8";
                    worksheetQRS.Cell("J1").Value = "QRS Day 9";
                    worksheetQRS.Cell("K1").Value = "QRS Day 10";
                    worksheetQRS.Cell("L1").Value = "QRS Weekly Total Test";

                }

                worksheetQRS.Cell($"A{loopCt}").Value = item.Identifier;

                for (int i = 0; i < QRSDaily.Count(); i++)
                {
                    columnQRS += 1;
                    worksheetQRS.Cell($"{alphabet[columnQRS]}{loopCt}").Value = QRSDaily[i];

                }

                worksheetQRS.Cell($"L{loopCt}").Value = QRSWeek;


                workbook.Save();
```

TL:DR; 
Writing data to an existing spreadsheet with multiple sheets, 
Written inside a foreach loop

Problem: I'm attempting to target one sheet at a time, write data, move on to the next sheet and write data, but its writing the same data to all sheets within the workbook and I cant find anything in the documentation about this particular scenario.

Thanks for reading,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always using the first Worksheet in the Workbook:

```
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheet(1);
                                   ^
```

You need to use a variable for the worksheet number or use the `workbook.AddWorksheet()` method. This is covered under [Creating Multiple Worksheets](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Creating-Multiple-Worksheets) in the documentation.

Comment: Hey Raidri, thanks for the reply, in my second export section labeled QRS export I use the following code;  

//QRS Export

                var worksheetQRS = workbook.Worksheet(2);

does this declaration not establish the second sheet? I toyed with this and tried to use the sheet names instead of the position number before posting but the same effect...

Comment: Fixed! Your direction back to the documentation got me on the right track... What I didn't realize I had done was I had used Open XML SDK (I ended up frustrated with it and went back to researching other, perhaps simpler ways to write in excel) to create the spreadsheet and then Closed XML to write in it, somewhere between there and here something was jumbled. I commented out the OpenXML creator and added the code you referenced and it works like a dream.